# IIS thows different exceptions when debugging from visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, iis

I've been trying debugging a web application from my Visual Studio using my IIS but when It's about to load the page in my output window I see the following exceptions

A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpParseException' occurred in System.Web.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpParseException' occurred in System.Web.dll
The thread 0x1188 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xc20 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
The thread 0x1880 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x187c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in System.Web.dll
The program '[3936] w3wp.exe: Managed' has exited with code -2 (0xfffffffe).

I tried to enable 32 bit compatibilty but i get other exceptions: System.Web
Entry Point Not Found Exception

I've tried to reinstal all frameworks but nothing, My OS is a 64bits windows 7

Please, does anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.